# Floating div two column layout blank space

Tags: css, html, css-float

I have X posts, each with fixed width and unknown height and want them to be in two columns in a single div-wrapper. However, when I put them all on float left, this happens.

[image]

How can I remove blank space?

Comment: you need to be a little more specific on how you would like to render the posts in order. So you would like to remove blank space, which means that your div's will render out of order. There needs to be a gap to keep form order.

Comment: I was have the same issue., solved it by giorgio answer.

Answer (score 2):

add clear: right to the even blocks and clear:left to the odd ones!

```
<style type="text/css">
    .odd { float: left; clear: left; }
    .even { float: right; clear: right; }
</style>

<div class="odd">content</div>
<div class="even">content</div>
<div class="odd">content</div>
<div class="even">content</div>
<div class="odd">content</div>
```

Comment: Worked, but not really like what I want, Well, was close at least, I just found its not 100% solve issue. still have issue, if all even was long and all odd was short in height, I got blank space again.

Answer (score 1):

Use `:nth-child(odd) {clear:both;}`

**[Working DEMO](http://jsbin.com/ajitir/3/edit)**

**CSS**

```
.outer {border:solid #f00; padding:10px;overflow:auto}
.outer div{border:solid 1px #f00; float:left; margin:5px}
.outer div:nth-child(odd) {clear:both;}
```

**HTML**

```
<div class="outer">
  <div >
    content content content content <br>content content content content <br>content content content content <br>content content content content <br>content content content content <br>content content content content <br></div>
<div >
     content content content content <br>content content content content <br>content content content  content <br>
</div>
<div >
     content content content content <br>content content content content <br>content content content content <br>content content content content <br>content content content content <br>content content content content <br>
</div>
<div>
     content content content content <br>content content content content <br>content content content content <br>content content content content <br>content content content content <br>content content content content <br>
</div>
<div >
     content content content content <br>content content content content <br>content content content content <br>content content content content <br>content content content content <br>content content content content <br>
</div>
  </div>
```

Comment: I see a gap below 2nd div( checked your demo)

Comment: +1,This gap below 2nd div can't be avoided,I think this is the best answer for the question

Answer (score 0):

Try to add after the second block the following :

```
<div style="clear:both">&nbsp;</div>
```

It should do the trick

Comment: Since the posts have variable height, it is unpredictable when this happens. This was just exaqmple, normally it can happen after any of blocks.

Answer (score -1):

Make a `left` div container and a `right` div container and add your posts to these instead of simply using `float: left`...

Comment: I agree because having variable heights on posts would just create a mess with just float: left. You are going to need a structure.

Comment: Since I dont know height of the blocks( assume it is random), one column could be much more longer than the other one.

Comment: Same issue will happen, and this is not answer ! you can right it as a comment.