# Floated images in Image Gallery Have Spacing Issues

Tags: css, image, css-float, figure

I am trying to use the `float` property to create a page that looks like a two-column image gallery. It’s almost there, but there are awkward spaces within columns that I don’t know how to eliminate. Does the solution involve clearing some of the floats?

Screenshot of the issue:

[image: Screenshot]

Code:

```css
#image-gallery figure {
  text-align: center;
  font-family: 'Alegreya Sans', sans-serif;
}
figure img {
  margin-top: 10px;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
  width: 100%;
  border: 3px solid purple;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
#image-gallery {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  list-style: none;
}
@media screen and (min-width: 500px) {
  #image-gallery img {
    width: 45%;
  }
  #image-gallery li {
    float: left;
    width: 45%;
    margin: 2.5%;
  }
}
```

```html
<section>
  <div>
    <ul id="image-gallery">
      <li>
        <figure>
          <img src="street-art-banksy.jpg" alt='missing' />
          <figcaption><a href="street-art-banksy.jpg">Street Art | Banksy</a>`</figcaption>`
        </figure>
      </li>

      <li>
        <figure>
          <img src="SoulForSale.jpg" alt="missing" />
          <figcaption><a href="SoulForSale.jpg">Soul For Sale | Bosoletti</a>`</figcaption>`
        </figure>
      </li>

      <li>
        <figure>
          <img src="ColorRain.jpg" alt="missing" />
          <figcaption><a href="ColorRain.jpg">Color Rain | Chris Wiedmann</a>`</figcaption>`
        </figure>
      </li>

      <li>
        <figure>
          <img src="NataliaRak.jpg" alt="missing" />
          <figcaption><a href="NataliaRak.jpg">Mural | Natalia Rak</a>`</figcaption>`
        </figure>
      </li>

      <li>
        <figure>
          <img src="Jetsonoroma-Lola.jpg" alt="missing" />
          <figcaption><a href="Jetsonoroma-Lola.jpg">Lola | Jetsonoroma</a>`</figcaption>`
        </figure>
      </li>

      <li>
        <figure>
          <img src="JoeCaslin-TheCastle.jpg" alt="missing" />
          <figcaption><a href="JoeCaslin-TheCastle.jpg">The Castle | Joe Caslin</a>
          </figcaption>
        </figure>
      </li>

      <li>
        <figure>
          <img src="RenaissanceMasters-OwenDippie.jpg" alt="missing" />
          <figcaption><a href="RenaissanceMasters-OwenDippie.jpg">Michelangelo, Raphael, Donatello, and Leonardo | Owen Dippie</a>
          </figcaption>
        </figure>
      </li>

      <li>
        <figure>
          <img src="VariousAndGold-Facetime.jpg" alt="missing" />
          <figcaption><a href="VariousAndGold-Facetime.jpg">Facetime | Various and Gold</a>
          </figcaption>
        </figure>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</section>
```

Comment: where is the Screenshot?

Comment: @GoodBadandUgly The image source was hidden in the Markdown of the question. I included it.

Comment: Try to use `display:inline-block; vertical-align:top;` instead of `float:left;`. You get more intuitive results this way.

Comment: This is a possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12729629/floating-div-two-column-layout-blank-space.

Comment: Thanks for suggesting display: inline-block; vertical-align:top; - However, I'm confused about why I would use that code in this case. I usually only use "inline-block"  for text.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a css clear on all the odd children.

```
li:nth-child(odd) {
    clear: left;
}
```

Checkout the following articles to learn more about `float` and `clear`.

- https://css-tricks.com/all-about-floats/
- https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/clear

Comment: Hey I had a followup question to my original post that I was hoping you could help me with. I want to add another breakpoint to break my two column image gallery into a three column one if the user widens the window even more than before. However, images are stuck on the left side and center like so : https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B-1e2Ni5AJalUG4xeWdKWWJ6dWM/view?usp=sharing   - Any thoughts on how to fix?

Comment: One way would be to use `li:nth-child(3n + 1)` instead of `li:nth-child(odd)` in a new breakpoint.  [Checkout this JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/jqnmv1of/).